# Sencha ExtJs Row Widget Collapse problem on Grid refresh

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

I'm using "Ext.grid.plugin.RowWidget" in ExtJs 6.5.3 (classic toolkit).

I have create a nested in nested grid using it.
Below is attached screenshot of the grid.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'/admin/api/site',
    method: 'POST',
    params : params                         
        success: function( response, opts ) {
             var grid = Ext.getCmp('eq-grid');
             var store = Ext.StoreManager.lookup('equipmentfla');                                                                         
             store.add(cairnet); // cairnet consist of form.getValues()
             grid.getView().dataSource.reload();  
          },
       failure: function( response, opts ) {

          }
})
```

[Before-adding.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntXuV.png)

[After-adding.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfeZb.png)

It works when the grid is not expanded while adding.

Problem: While adding, if record is kept expanded then (After calling reload method) the row body becomes empty (see After-adding.png). But after refreshing browser, record is present.

Note: After many research i've found out that this is a bug and also got a Override for it, but it only works with "Modern" Toolkit [link for override](http://www.coding-ideas.de/2018/03/30/extjs-modern-6-5-3-expanded-rows-collapsed-after-reload-refresh/)